# significance of multiple operators in one variable declaration

Tags: javascript

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4433812/1252748) which tests whether or not a page has been cached, I see this variable declaration.

```
var isCached = currentCookie !== null;
```

What is the significance of the `=` and `!==` operators together in one statement?

Comment: The significance? One sets a value (=), one determines what the value is (!==, strict inequality). The same as any other assignment operation, like "a = 42 + 69".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that expression means:

*`isCached` is true when `currentCookie !== null`, false otherwise*

you should read it like

```
var isCached = (currentCookie !== null)
```

or more verbosely is equivalent to

```
var isCached;
if (currentCookie !== null) {
   isCached = true;
}
else {
   isCached = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That snippet is equivalent with:

```
var isCached = (currentCookie !== null);
```

In other words, `isCached` is set to `true` if and only if `currentCookie` is strictly not equal to the null reference.